# How can one reverse the effects of an intellect devourer's ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, ability-scores

In the next story arc, the party are heading down through some old Dwarven mines, so naturally they're going to come across a few underdark beasties, namely the Intellect Devourer.

Currently, they are all level 5 and will likely remain so while doing this arc.  What options do the players have for reversing the effects of Devour Intellect?

I am interested in *all* of the ways that this can be reversed, preferably starting with options available to second-tier parties. (Character levels 5 through 10, p. 10, Basic Rules).

Comment: Is your intent to have only one, or multiple, ways for them to overcome this depending upon how they follow or pick up clues, treasure, NPC interactions, etc?

Comment: preferably as many ways as they can potentially have, but they are only level 5 so the options may well be limited

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the standard answer would be "Greater Restoration", however:

> As the guy who wrote that ecology, you don't. Here's how Intellect Devourers work. They devour your intellect then they meld into your brain and turn you into their prey. It's in the Monster Manual. They're ambush predators and strike when you're alone. So, ideally, you can't really recover the lost intelligence. It takes a long rest. So, if you get ambushed (and they don't attack parties. They attack single or duo victims), you get stunned, they take over your brain and then they make you lure others.

Parsing that is somewhat complex, but it seems as though (and this follows for a CR2 creature IMO) that you should regain your mental capabilities after a long rest.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/DnDBehindTheScreen/comments/3cridh/5e_intellect_devourer_how_do_you_regain/csym9ca

Comment: Might help this answer if you include the verbiage where it says long rest regains lost ability points.

Comment: @Slagmoth The problem is that the link to edit is closed, and that is in the original language from someone who was apparently in on the dev.   That sentence is odd, to say the least, in that it may be a metaphorical allusion to where your intelligence goes, or something he forgot to edit out.  The key piece of the cited answer is "you don't."

Comment: @Slagmoth I've included that portion with the post. The problem is, it does not say 'a long rest regains lost ability points'. To my knowledge only greater restoration does that. However, the quoted source, in context, seems to imply that it is the case with "It takes a long rest."

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find anything either, according to Jeremy Crawford only lists Greater Restoration on Twitter in response to this very question. Obviously Wish would do it as well by duplicating GR. Nice story arc leading around an idiot PC till you find a cure though.

Comment: both answers are exactly what I'm after but I feel this one gives a little more insight into how Intellect Devourers actually work, so I'm marking this one as correct. Thank you!

Comment: A Causal link proving that redditor was really the one to write said entry is missing. It cannot be taken as authoritative, -1.

Comment: Specially when it contradicts a sage advice entry.

Comment: "As the guy who wrote that ecology" means that reddit user wrote [a fan-made ecology post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnDBehindTheScreen/comments/3987kk/intellect_devourer/), which is part of a /r/DnDBehindTheScreen subreddit project to add some flavor to the creatures in the Monster Manual.  It's explicitly not a rules reference nor in any capacity official.

Answer (score 24):

*Greater Restoration* will cure:

> - Any
>     reduction
>     to
>     one
>     of
>     the
>     target’s
>     ability
>     scores

*Wish* can duplicate *Greater Restoration*, or it can do this:

> You
>   allow
>   up
>   to
>   twenty
>   creatures
>   that
>   you
>   can
>   see
>   to
>   regain
>   all
>   hit
>   points,
>   and
>   you
>   end
>   all
>   effects
>   on
>   them
>   described
>   in
>   the
>   *greater
>   restoration*
>   spell.

Killing them then bringing them back to life *might* fix this, especially with *True Resurrection*. Unfortunately, Devour Intellect isn't a curse, disease, or poison, so even *True Resurrection* is by no means guaranteed to work.

Comment: +1. In another thread (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/is-a-character-that-had-their-brain-devoured-by-an-intellect-devourer-dead-can), there's what looks like a quote from the manual that says, "... The intellect devourer is also forced out if the target regains its devoured brain by means of a wish. ..." Which seems to indicate that a brain can be regained, though I'm not sure if it would be a new brain or what.

Answer (score 18):

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 131) includes ["Relaxation"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#Relaxation) as an option for a downtime activity, which lets a character recover reduced ability scores by spending a week of downtime:

> ***Resources.*** Relaxation requires one week. A character
>   needs to maintain at least a modest lifestyle while relaxing to gain
>   the benefit of the activity.
>
> ***Resolution.*** Characters who maintain at least a modest lifestyle
>   while relaxing gain several benefits. While relaxing, a character
>   gains advantage on saving throws to recover from long-acting diseases
>   and poisons. In addition, at the end of the week, a character can end
>   one effect that keeps the character from regaining hit points, or
>   **can restore one ability score that has been reduced to less than its
>   normal value**. This benefit cannot be used if the harmful effect was
>   caused by a spell or some other magical effect with an ongoing
>   duration.

Comment: Good find. It might improve your answer if you justify that the intellect devourer's effect isn't a spell or magical so that this downtime option can be used for it.

Comment: @Bloodcinder: It is magical ("The target must succeed on a DC 12 Intelligence saving throw against this magic"), so the argument would need to be that it's not one with an "ongoing duration", i.e. it's just an instantaneous effect (like *animate dead*).

Answer (score 9):

The spells *Greater Restoration* and *Wish* would reverse the Intelligence lost from the Devour Intellect ability of an Intellect Devourer.  According to Jeremy E. Crawford, one of the lead designers of 5th Edition, has the following to say about your question, which you can find [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/04/27/how-do-you-fix-intelligence-devoured-by-an-intellect-devourer/):

"The greater restoration spell can restore an ability score that's been reduced."

Jeremy Crawford is known for concise, but thorough, explanations and would list the easiest method possible so *Greater Restoration* would be the easiest possible method and would mean that it couldn't be recovered via long rest since that would be a much easier method than a 5th level spell.