# What can I do as a level 3 sorcerer to undo Intellect Devourer Ability Score damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, sorcerer, ability-scores

Is there anything like [*greater restoration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration) available to me at level 3? Or is there something I can do as a level three sorcerer to undo the effects of a [Intellect Devourer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/intellect-devourer)'s ability score reduction on a fallen player character?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry not on a system it’s tabletop  D&D 5th edition

Comment: @AlanMark D&D 5th edition is indeed the system, as in the rpg system used, the set of rules. I have added the corresponding tag to the question to indicate this.

Comment: Which effect of the monster do you mean? The reduction to Intelligence or the aftereffects of it taking over a body?

Comment: Just the intellect damage

Answer (score 24):

## Hire Help

While you can't do anything personally, you may be able to go to a town large enough that has spellcasting services where you could employ someone that can cast Greater Restoration.

Whether or not this is an actual possibility will rely on your DM and the world you play in.

### Plot Hook help

Getting this done is a great plot hook set-up! Whether it's in the search or in a barter for payment  - there's a lot here for the group to do.

Comment: And if the party can't afford it at level 3, there might be a spellcaster who would provide the service as payment for some task...

Comment: @chrylis Keep you and your plot hooks out of this :) But seriously great point - adding :)

Comment: That does seem like a strange oversight.  Most creatures that reduce ability scores say when and how you recover -- like the Shadow where you get it back after a short or long rest.  But I suppose if your mind literally got devoured, it makes sense that you need some high end restoration magic to get it back.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym They can straight-up eat your brain and teleport into your head if they're close enough and you fail the saving throw, so that definitely requires some additional work. It seems the less-dangerous intelligence drain goes away after a rest in 5e, though.

Comment: @JAB No, I know about the brain-teleporty thing, that isn't what I'm talking about.  Where are you getting that int-drain goes away ever, short of a restoration spell?  JCrawford was asked about this on Twitter some time ago; he said Greater Restoration is the only way.  If you were reading https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87639 note that the 'ecology' quote in the top answer is from a *fan-work* that has no official backing (see the comments on that answer for details).  5e has no way to recover lost ability scores except that spell and any monster-specific rules.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I don't have copies of the 5e sourcebooks so was looking at online references, so i guess the site i was looking at (5esrd) is inaccurate. https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/monsters-foes/monsters-by-type/aberrations/intellect-devourer-3pp/ There is also a copy of an MM page on the WotC site that does not mention that restoration but it does not identify the edition, which is why i was looking for something else.

Comment: @JAB Ah... yeah, that is a completely different stat block.  The Intellect Devourer in the MM is CR2, not 7 (thus the question about how a 3rd level character could deal with it), and it has no spellcasting ability.  The version on that website appears to be an update of the Intellect Devourer from the 3.5 SRD, which is indeed CR 7 and has a set of 'psi-like abilities'.  (Note that the SRD copyright info at the bottom says "2002-2003", so clearly that isn't from anything put out during 5th edition.)

Comment: The 5eSRD page also has "3pp" in its heading, indicating that it's not an official 5e creature (or rather, not the official 5e version of the creature).